# i need to change output folder of maven src/main/resources folder from target/classes or WEB-INF/classes to /resources in WAR

Tags: maven

Can anyone help me, I need to change **output folder** of **Maven** for **src/main/resources** folder from **WEB-INF/classes** **to /resources in WAR**.
and no file of src/main/resources copied to **WEB-INF/classes**

Answer (score 1):

All `src/main/resources` are non-java files which will be available on the classpath. If you want them under `/resources` in the war, then put those files under the [warSourceDirectory](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceDirectory), so in your case `src/main/webapp/resources`.